# Change image of sky every few seconds with an animation

Tags: aframe, webvr

I need change the image of sky every few seconds with an animation.

like [this](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/). But without the event click, in my case, i need the change of picture with time.

```
    <a-assets>
        <img id="water" src="./3D/letras/Agua.jpg"/>
        <img id="air" src="./3D/letras/Aire.jpg"/>
        <img id="horizont" src="./3D/letras/Horizonte.jpg"/>
        <img id="hector" src="./3D/letras/hecxtor.jpg"/>
    </a-assets>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.
You make two animations: a fade-in, and a fade-out:

```
<a-sky foo>
   <a-animation id="fadein-animation"></a-animation>
   <a-animation id="fadein-animation"></a-animation>
</a-sky>
```

The idea is to animate the opacity, and when the image is not visible, switch the source:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    var self = this.el
    var fadeInAnim = document.querySelector("#fadein-animation")
    var fadeOutAnim = document.querySelector("#fadeout-animation")
    var images = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"]
    var switchflip = 1
    fadeOutAnim.addEventListener("animationend", (e) => {
      self.setAttribute("material", "src", images[switchflip])
      switchflip = switchflip === 1 ? 0 : 1
      self.emit('fadein')
    })
    fadeInAnim.addEventListener("animationend", (e) => {
      self.emit('fadeout')
    })
 }
})
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b8jdmnfx/19/).

Comment: I'd use the animation component, but [this issue](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/issues/137) makes it really hard to daisychain the animations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Your example only works with a second, modify the time in the setTimeOut function to 5 seconds, It works on the first image, the others add the effect every 1 second. I need it to disappear every 5 seconds. [code](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorRoldan/7pq6zh7s/)

Comment: i've put a `setTimeout` in one of the listeners, is it what you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/7pq6zh7s/2/ ?

Comment: Yeah, It solutions to my problem... Thanks for your help!! :D